# Edit the title in a meta-box on a custom-made theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress project where I need to edit the name of some blocks so it will be easier for the end customer to understand what each block means.
I use a own made template and I will insert a image below of what block I mean:

(Image removed)

[image]

In which file can I access these name and just change them in the front-end?

Comment: Sorry, are you using a premium theme or a did you make it yourself?

Comment: @Rich own-made theme

Comment: Understood, did you install a slider plugin or similar? If so which one?

Comment: @Rich we have installed the Slider Revolution plugin

Comment: Posted my answer, hope it helps

Comment: @Rich Can I use a for-each loop instead of a switch case if I want to edit some other meta-boxes also? – anderssinho 15 mins ago

Comment: You can but its easier just to add more cases to the switch, have changed my answer below to show you how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the gettext filter to force a rename in the admin if your client will find that more helpful, you would add something like the below in your functions.php file of your custom theme:

```
    function mytheme_rs_rename($translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain) {

    if ( is_admin() ) {

            switch ( $translated_text ) {

                case 'Slider' :

                    $translated_text = __( 'New Name Here', 'mytheme_text_domain' );
                    break;

                case 'Other String to Change' :

                    $translated_text = __( 'Other String Change Here', 'theme_text_domain' );
                    break;

            }

        }

        return $translated_text;
    }

    add_filter( 'gettext', 'mytheme_rs_rename', 10, 3 );
```